# Strip `FALSE` prefix from Boolean list using the y-combinator? Stumped

Tags: lambda-calculus, y-combinator

Given a list, e.g. `(f: f FALSE (g: g FALSE (h: h TRUE FALSE)))`, write an operator that removes all leading `FALSE`s and returns only the tail that starts with `TRUE`. For this example the operator should return just `(h: h TRUE FALSE)`.

This is an exercise, in fact a level, in this game called "functional" that I've become obsessed with. In the previous level we were required to generalized \Omega into the y-combinator so I imagine that this level requires the y-combinator in order to handle a `FALSE` prefix of arbitrary length.

I'm able to handle a single `FALSE` prefix with `(b: c: IF b (f: f b c) c)`.  Imagining that operator as `f` I'm guessing the answer should look something like `(b: c: IF b (f: f b c) (Y c))`. The game is rejecting that answer complaining about "no reduction (grew too big)".

I'm clearly baffled by the y-combinator. Can someone show me how to use it correctly?

Also, what is this crazy syntax the game is using? I don't see it used anywhere else.

As requested, a link to functional's page on Steam is [here](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1636730/functional/). I also recently uncovered a link the projects page on github [here](https://yancouto.github.io/functional/functional/index.html).

Comment: I just discovered that my proposed solution fails for for lists with a `FALSE` prefix length of 3 and above. Crud. Still a long way to go.

Comment: I haven't seen this game. Mind including a link? I think if Y acts as it should that `Y (r: (b: c: IF b (f: f b c) (c (r r))))` might be closer but I can't test that.

Comment: @DanD. Just added a link to the article.

Comment: Now I'm working with `(l: l (b: c: b (PAIR b c) (c (d: e: d (PAIR d e) e))))` which passes the level, but I still don't think it's right. But at least this function is self-referential.

Comment: judging from the [screenshot #3](https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/1636730/ss_595507772d4e19192acfb5dbc129edf72aaeacd5.jpg?t=1626399695), lists seem to be defined as `PAIR h t o = o h t` and `NIL o x = x`.

Comment: but it's _not_ `PAIR h t c n = c h t`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `Y(f: x: (FST x) x (f(SND x)))`.

By using Y-combinator, it returns the whole list (`x`) if the head (`FST x`) is TRUE and recursively calls itself taking the tail (`SND x`) as an argument otherwise.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Also, you should check how to format your posts properly here 
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while stuck on this question. Let me explain why an incorrect answer doesn't work, then give the solution.

I first tried to solve this problem "imperatively." I tried to sketch a solution that said, "if the first element is TRUE, use the list (and we're done), otherwise call itself with skip-the-first-element." This incorrect solution looks like

```
t: IF (FST t) t (Y (x: SND t))
```

Look what happens with the test cases:

Case 1 (list=FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE): ... failure.

Case 2 (list=TRUE FALSE): The first element in the list is TRUE, so the `IF` statement returns the entire list. Success.

Case 3 (list=FALSE TRUE): The `IF` statement fails, this reduces to

```
(f: f (PAIR FALSE (PAIR TRUE FALSE))) t: IF (FST t) t (Y (x: SND t))
...
Y (x: SND (PAIR FALSE (PAIR TRUE FALSE)))
...
SND (PAIR FALSE (PAIR TRUE FALSE))
...
PAIR TRUE FALSE # single element list containing TRUE
```

Case 3 succeeds, but only by accident. The Y combinator isn't doing anything helpful.

---

Let me copy some text from the problem:

> Suppose you want to write a function that receives two arguments and applies *itself* to both arguments in inverted order. You can write: `F = Y (f: x:y: f y x)`.

Pondering the above example and the case 3 above finally made it clear how to use the Y Combinator. You need to start with the Y Combinator, and use a function that you want to apply to itself. This function will have a list argument, but will more or less follow the same logic as I tried to implement the first time. Correct solution:

```
Y (f: x: IF (FST x) x (f (SND x)))
```

This solution says:

Apply this function to itself. If the first element in the list is TRUE, return the entire list and we're done (the `IF (FST x) x` part).

Otherwise, apply itself on the skip-the-first-element list (the `f (SND x)` part).